# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) on Mac

Tags: php, html, mysql, database-connection

I am currently using this PHP code:

```html
<?php
// Get a connection for the database
require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

// Create a query for the database
$query = "SELECT username, message FROM messages";

// Get a response from the database by sending the connection
// and the query
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

// If the query executed properly proceed
if($response){

echo '<table align="left"
cellspacing="5" cellpadding="8">

<tr><td align="left"><b>username</b></td>
<td align="left"><b>Message</b></td></tr>';

// mysqli_fetch_array will return a row of data from the query
// until no further data is available
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){

echo '<tr><td align="left">' . 
$row['username'] . '</td><td align="left">' . 
$row['message'] . '</td><td align="left">';

echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

} else {

echo "Couldn't issue database query<br />";

echo mysqli_error($dbc);

}

// Close connection to the database
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

To try and display selections from the table 'messages' using external code:

```html
<?php
DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');
DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'Cheese');

$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' .
mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

To connect to the database with. However, it only returns the error "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)", which I have found no (Mac-compatible) answers for solving. The server was running and available during this.

Comment: Try specifying `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Most mysql drivers try to short-circuit `localhost` to the unix socket path.

Comment: That returns Could not connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)? I used localhost as the hostname in the database

Comment: Then chances are that either: 1. MySQL isn't running. 2. MySQL isn't running on the default port. 3. Something else on your system is preventing the connection, eg a firewall or other security thing.

Comment: Also you should stop using `@` to suppress errors. It's like shoving your fingers in your ears and yelling so that you can't hear the fire alarm going off. Errors and warnings should be _fixed_, not suppressed.

Comment: in your php ini, try setting `mysqli.default_socket=` , to use the builtin mysql defaults.

Comment: Connect using the `mysql` command in Terminal and use the `status` command. It will tell you the socket file path, for example in my case `UNIX socket: /tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: This worked! Thanks!